# sql whitelisting not working when connected to a university intranet

Tags: sql-server, web-hosting, whitelist

I have been having troubles to establish database connection using the MS SQL Management Studio. It was working fine when I was using a local internet service provider. However, when I began to use the university internet, I am not able to connect to the db, although I sql-whitelist the ip. I have no ideas how to manage this issue. I have to connect to the db to manage it, but I am receiving "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server..." Do you have any idea? Is this something that my hosting company should figure out?

Thanks!

Comment: what connection string are you using to connect to database??? The error you have shown can mean many things. 1st need to see your connection string before you do anything else to fix this issue.

Comment: I am sure I have a working connection string. It was working fine before using the university internet : Data Source=xxx.yyy.zz.www;Initial Catalog=a_b;User Id=user;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: and I think it is not about that I have problems connecting to the sql instance using the web application but it is about not being able to connect to the remote sql instance using the sql server management studio.

Comment: it doesnt really help the way you have shown your connection string anyway, are you trying to connect to default instance of sql server? Make sure two things, if you are connecting to Default instance of sql server you should only use the `Machine_Name` in your Data Source, if you are connecting to named instance then you have to use `MachineName\InstanceName` in Data Source, Also make sure remote connection is allowed to sql server.

Comment: I think that it is about my IP assigned by the university intranet. I white-list my ip using the control panel provided by the hosting company, but i can never connect to the remote sql server instance. My IP was working when I was using my local service provider not university intranet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reasonably good chance you are being blocked by a firewall at the university. They probably block/allow based on IP. Universities should not allow all IP's in the University net to have access by default.

You may have had a firewall exception for the old address. You can check if port is blocked by using the telnet command from any windows client command line.

telnet 127.0.0.1 1433 -- substitute your sql server ip address or name

telnet 127.0.0.1 22334 -- no reason for the this port to be open

This is what a blocked port looks like

```
C:\>telnet localhost 22334
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 22334:
Connect failed

C:\>
```

If 1433 is open and associate with ms-sql you get a different behavior (although it is pretty odd) -- you may have to close the command prompt or kill the telnet process. In any case, this confirms the port is open or closed. If port is open and you can't connect, you have a connection string problem or something obscure.

Comment: when I used the sql server ip address, I got the "Connect failed" output like the one you shared. So, this means that the server and/or the port is blocked by the university firewall?

Comment: You are being blocked. It may be a university firewall, or a local firewall on the server machine itself. Something is blocking you or the server is down (or something even more obscure). Presumably they are allowing remote connections at the server since you could get in before, but that could have changed too and that would be blocking you.

Comment: it has to be the university firewall thing, since I was able to connect just yesterday and since the hosting company said everything looks fine on server-side. I will contact with the university admins to unblock the server ip and the port number. I hope this is doable and do not create security threats for them. Thanks for your help !